# BroadCast Receiver not launching activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, hidden

I am implemeting a hidden app. I wantt to hide the app in the phone and launch it when I call a certain number.

In first place I have an alias-activity declared on the manifest, and I hide it. It is MainActivity2:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME = new ComponentName(
            "com.example.susan.oculta.launcher", "com.example.susan.oculta.launcher.Launcher");
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);...
```

Some Manifest lines:

```
<activity-alias
        android:name=".launcher.Launcher"
        android:targetActivity=".launcher.Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

With this code I am able to hide the icon.

I also have a BroadCast Receiver. This one:

```
public class LaunchAppViaDialReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (null == bundle)
        return;
    String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    //here change the number to your desired number
    if (phoneNubmer.equals("12345")) {
        Log.i("reciving", "receeeeeeeeeiving");

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);

        setResultData(null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "aaaa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

The problem is that when I dial "12345" the Toast shows up, but MainActivity does not. I have tried adding flags to the intent and starting the intent finding it by package. But the intent seems to not be working.
The log "receeeeeeeeeiving" also shows up.

Comment: I tried the same code in several phones and it sometimes works, it sometimes does not. It seems that MIUI OS has something to do with this.
Anyway, I made a workaround. I start a notification when the call is received. From there, the user can press the notification and start main activity. Works for my app

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (phoneNubmer.equals("12345")) {

     Log.i("reciving", "receeeeeeeeeiving"); 
     Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
     context.startActivity(i);
     Toast.makeText(context, "aaaa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: It did not work, Log and Toast show up, but not the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
ComponentName componentName = new 
ComponentName(packageName, packageName + "your_ALIAS_ACTIVITY");
i.setComponent(componentName);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: If I call the alias activity, the app crashes because it is disabled. If I call ComponentName(packageName,
                        packageName + "myMainActivity"); the behavior is the same: toast and log show up, but the activity is not showing

Answer (score 0):

When an app is initially installed, it's in the "stopped" state. It remains in the stopped state until the user has explicitly launched one of its activities. If the user force closes the app, it is returned to the stopped state.

**When an app is in the stopped state, none of its broadcast receivers will ever be called.** I suspect that the only reason your `BroadcastReceiver` is being called at all is because you launched your main activity at some point during development. Now, being disabled, it won't run.  If you were to install this app on a fresh device (or force close it to reset it to the stopped state) you would no longer even see your log and toast.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do not think it is that, because if I don't use this part:
 PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME = new ComponentName(
            "com.example.susan.oculta.launcher", "com.example.susan.oculta.launcher.Launcher");
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
The activity is still not showing up. Of course I will need to set up a service to keep the broadcastreceiver alive, but I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this :

- You give SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in the Manifest, then you redirect the user (at runtime) to 'Draw over other apps' setting. This way, you can launch any background/killed activity on Android 10 or higher.

For those who have the same issue on MIUI OS phones (Xiaomi), you have multiple work arounds :

- SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW can't save you with Xiaomi phones. Therefore, you need an AccessibilityService to bypass the MIUI limitation, otherwise, you can just set a Full-Screen High-Priority notification that will definitely launch activity if the phone is in "Idle" state. If the user is using the phone, the notification appears in the drawer and will only launch activity if the user clicks on it.

These were all the non-root solutions.